# cocos2dx crash at random places

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm using cocos2dx version 2.2.6 and facing a crash that occurs randomly while running the scene. In EAGLView.mm swapBuffers method 
at line

```
if(![_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER])
```

I've searched about it and most answers were to add these two lines to AppDelegate.cpp

```
void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground() {
     CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();
}
void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() {
     CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();
}
```

but It didn't work.

Comment: You cannot debug these kind of crashes like this. You have to go step by step. Like use the breakpoints and Logs to track the code which is crashing.

Comment: need more log to help.

Comment: @einverne
this's the log but the error doesn't occur every time I run the scene 

malloc: *** error for object 0x13266a2f8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(lldb)